# Was the firing squad scene in Hell Bent inspired by the similar situation in Carnage of Krell?

Tags: doctor-who, the-clone-wars, inspiration

In the Doctor Who episode, Hell Bent, the Doctor is facing a firing squad, who are made up of those who respect him more than they respect the person giving them orders. In this case it is president Rassilon. When given the order to execute the Doctor, the entire firing squad misses. They then, one-by-one, go and stand alongside the Doctor dropping their guns in a pile.

Which is very similar to how the clone troopers acted when Pong Krell ordered the execution of Fives and Jesse during the Umbaran arc of the Clone Wars ([S4E10](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Carnage_of_Krell)).

Given that the Doctor Who episode was first broadcast four years after the Clone Wars episode, has there been any official admission of the one being inspired by the other?

Or is it that there is an example with greater precedence which they were both inspired by?

Comment: Probably not. They really aren't that similar, and reluctant executioners are a common enough plot device. The story of an executioner who went to stand with the condemned  goes back at least to an account of the Forty Martyrs of Sebaste circa 370AD.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forty_Martyrs_of_Sebaste#Martyrdom

Comment: I get that the plot itself is a trope older than television. I am looking at the actual execution scenes as a visual thing, especially the firing squad missing as a whole and then walking forward and dropping their guns in a pile.  Those are very specific visual themes.

Comment: A firing squad is something assembled to execute a person condemned to death. This is the case in your Star Wars cartoon, as they are already a prisoner. Although Rassilon does refer to his soldiers as a 'firing squad', the setup is very different. He comes to interrogate The Doctor as he escaped the Confession Dial but orders them to shoot on a whim. The Doctor has been in front of a real firing squad before, in *War Games*. Knowing Moffatt's love of referencing classic Who, there's a better argument that it was inspired of that.